# Stroke with round cap is being shown half way in EditText

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-canvas, stroke

I want my edittext to only take 4 letters and each letter to have a white background with stroke of small circles as shown in the picture below

[image]

I have tried to create a customEditText and draw dashed path with a rounded stroke but the stroke is appearing just half way even when i increase stroke width as shown in the picture below.

[image]

```
public class PinEntryEditText extends AppCompatEditText {

float mSpace = 24; //24 dp by default
float mCharSize = 0;
float mNumChars = 4;
private float density;
private Paint paint;
private Path path;
private PathEffect effects;

public PinEntryEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
                        int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init(context, attrs);
}


private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    setBackgroundResource(0);

    float multi = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    mSpace = multi * mSpace; //convert to pixels for our density

    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

    paint.setStrokeWidth(10);
    paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);

    paint.setColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.clr_black));
    path = new Path();
    //array is ON and OFF distances in px (4px line then 2px space)
    /*Path cpath = new Path();
    cpath.addCircle(0,0,10, Path.Direction.CCW);*/

    effects = new DashPathEffect(new float[]{10,20,10,20},0);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    //super.onDraw(canvas);
    int availableWidth =
            getWidth() - getPaddingRight() - getPaddingLeft();
    if (mSpace < 0) {
        mCharSize = (availableWidth / (mNumChars * 2 - 1));
    } else {
        mCharSize =
                (availableWidth - (mSpace * (mNumChars - 1))) / mNumChars;
    }

    int startX = getPaddingLeft();
    int bottom = getHeight() - getPaddingBottom();

    for (int i=0; i< mNumChars; i++) {
        paint.setPathEffect(effects);
        path.moveTo(startX, bottom);
        path.lineTo(startX + mCharSize, bottom);
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

        if (mSpace < 0) {
            startX += mCharSize * 2;
        } else {
            startX += mCharSize + mSpace;
        }
    }
}
}
```

How will I make the stroke to appear complete and not half way or how will I be able to draw the dots on the first picture?

Comment: Are you trying to create a password field? Android has a built in property called input type. just set it to textPassword.
`android:inputType="textPassword"`

Comment: @chinnc Not a password field but a verification code field. with a maximum length of 4 letters

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below thing for your kind of solution.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/codeEditText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:maxLength="4"
    android:inputType="textPassword"/>
```

and In class file

```
EditText edittext = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.passWordEditText);
edittext.setTransformationMethod(new AsteriskPasswordTransformationMethod());
```

and This class implement for that,

```
public class AsteriskPasswordTransformationMethod extends PasswordTransformationMethod {
     private  String DOT = "\u2022";
     private String  BIGGER_DOT = "●";
    @Override
    public CharSequence getTransformation(CharSequence source, View view) {
        return new PasswordCharSequence(source);
    }

    private class PasswordCharSequence implements CharSequence {
        private CharSequence mSource;
        public PasswordCharSequence(CharSequence source) {
            mSource = source; // Store char sequence
        }
        public char charAt(int index) {
            return '*'; // This is the important part
        }
        public int length() {
            return mSource.length(); // Return default
        }
        public CharSequence subSequence(int start, int end) {
            return mSource.subSequence(start, end); // Return default
        }
    }
};
```

It will convert your star to any thing you needed.

```
 public char charAt(int index) {
                return '*'; // This is the important part
            }
```

you can replace with a bullet string so show like

```
 private  String DOT = "\u2022";
 private String  BIGGER_DOT = "●";
```

I know it might be later but it might help any other who looking for the same.